# PHP list gotcha? First var returns first character of second var

Tags: php, arrays, list

This must be a gotcha of some sort, but I just can’t see it. I’ve taken it out of my application and tested it in a separate script, and it performs the same way. Here’s the extracted code, but it has the same problem independently.

```
<?php

$actions[1] = '14-pictures-of-trees';
var_dump($actions[1]); // 1

$url = explode('-', $actions[1], 2);
var_dump($url); // 2

list($id, $url) = $url;
var_dump($id); // 3
var_dump($url); // 4
```

Here’s the results:

1. `string '14-pictures-of-trees' (length=20)`
2. `array

   0 => string '14' (length=2)

   1 => string 'pictures-of-trees' (length=17)`
3. `string 'p' (length=1)`
4. `string 'pictures-of-trees' (length=17)`

I’m expecting 3 to return `string '14'` but it doesn’t!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list` assigns its arguments starting with the last and ending with the first. This is fully explained in the [manual](http://php.net/list), specifically two warnings:

> **Warning**
> `list()` assigns the values starting with the right-most parameter. If you are using plain variables, you don't have to worry about this. But if you are using arrays with indices you usually expect the order of the indices in the array the same you wrote in the `list()` from left to right; which it isn't. It's assigned in the reverse order.
>
> **Warning**
> Modification of the array during `list()` execution (e.g. using `list($a, $b) = $b`) results in undefined behavior.

Therefore, your expression is basically like this:

```
$url = $url[1]; // $url is now "pictures-of-trees"
$id = $url[0];
```

Accessing a string as if were an array of characters, `$id` is now the first character of `$url`. Hence `p`.

Instead, use a different variable name for `$url` or assign them directly:

```
list($id, $url) = explode('-', $actions[1], 2);
```

Comment: Or `list($id, $url) = explode('-', $actions[1], 2);`

Answer (score 1):

What's happened is the variable `$url` is modified and overwritten with the second element of the previous array `$url` before `$id` is assigned.  This is because `list()` loads variables from right to left, not left to right.

When you access `$url[0]` once it has been converted to a string in the `list()` call, you get the first character, `p`, and that is what becomes stored in `$id`.

See the [notes on the `list()` docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) for info on the right to left assignments...

Answer (score 1):

`list` overwrites the `$url` variable before creating `$id`.

From the manual:

> Modification of the array during list() execution (e.g. using list($a,
>   $b) = $b) results in undefined behavior.

Using a different variable on the left hand side solves the problem:

```
list($id, $urx) = $url;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're re-assigning the variable `$url` while it's being used by the `list()` construct.  If you change the variable name, you'll get the result that you're expecting.  Keep in mind that `list()` assigns the values in a right-to-left fashion!

```
<?php 
$actions[1] = '14-pictures-of-trees'; 

$url = explode('-', $actions[1], 2); 
var_dump($url); // 2 

list($id, $url2) = $url; 
var_dump($id); // 3 
var_dump($url2); // 4
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the statement

```
list($id, $url) = $url;
```

You are modifying the array while you process it.